# Are the sequences $\frac{ih}{2}((1-ih)^{k}-(1+ih)^{k})$ and $\frac{1}{(1+h^{2})^{k}}\frac{ih}{2}((1-ih)^{k}-(1+ih)^{k})$ bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

I want to understand the explicit and the implicit Euler method better. Assume I have the initial value problem $y''+y=0$, $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$, which is of course solved by $y=\sin(x)$, and I convert this into a system of first-degree linear equations
\begin{equation*}
\left(\begin{matrix}y'\\z'\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}y\\z\end{matrix}\right)\text{.}
\end{equation*}
When I apply the explicit and the implicit Euler methods to the differential equation $y''+y=0$, with stepwidth $h>0$, I get approximation points that satisfy:
\begin{eqnarray*}
y_{k} & = & \frac{ih}{2}((1-ih)^{k}-(1+ih)^{k}) & \text{for the explicit Euler method}\\
\tilde{y}_{k} & = & \frac{ih}{2(1+h^{2})^{k}}((1-ih)^{k}-(1+ih)^{k}) & \text{for the implicit Euler method}
\end{eqnarray*}
I am interested in seeing how fast these sequences grow with $k$. My guess is that the first sequence is unbounded, whereas the second converges to zero. At least that is what I get for , but I have no idea how to prove this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use $|1\pm ih|=\sqrt{1+h^2}$. Or more generally, use polar coordinates for the powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta=\arctan h, r=\sqrt{1+h^2}$ and then
$$ 1+ih=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta), 1-ih=\sqrt{1+h^2}(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta). $$
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
y_{k} & = & \frac{ih}{2}((1-ih)^{k}-(1+ih)^{k}) \\
&=& hr^k\sin(k\theta).
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $h>0$, you have $r>1$ and $\theta\in(0,\frac\pi2)$ and hence $\{y_k\}$ diverges. Similarly
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tilde{y}_{k} & = & \frac{ih}{2(1+h^{2})^{k}}((1-ih)^{k}-(1+ih)^{k}) \\
&=&hr^{-k}\sin(k\theta).
\end{eqnarray*}
So $\{\tilde{y}_k\}$ converges to $0$ since $r>1$.

Comment: How do I know that $\sin(k\theta)$ does not converge to zero faster than $r^{k}$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Note that $|\sin(k\theta)|\le1$ and hence $|r^{-k}\sin(k\theta)|\le r^{-k}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.